# MQTT and Python - how to use hostname in topic?

Tags: python, mqtt, hostname

I am a total newbie to MQTT and Python on my Raspi. However, by using search and "G" a lot, I made it as far as I can capture and publish temperatures.
Too make things more simple in managing the data, I'd like to use the hostname in the topic.

So far I do:

```
client.publish("data/humidity_rel", "%.2f" %humidity)
```

what I'd like to do is using the hostname which I get like this

```
import socket
socket.gethostname()
host = socket.gethostname()
```

I thought my topic should look like

`client.publish("host/data/humidity_rel", "%.2f" %humidity)`
but simply adding "host" like this doesn't work.

tried all kinds of syntax but w/o success

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Neither the MQTT spec or the Paho Python MQTT client implementation will do what you want automatically, it's up to you to do the string substitution yourself.

```
client.publish(host+"/data/humidity_rel", "%.2f" %humidity)
```

or

```
client.publish('%s/data/humidity_rel' % host, "%.2f" %humidity)
```

or

```
client.publish('{}/data/humidity_rel'.format(host), "%.2f" %humidity)
```